# Saving Rmarkdown shiny as html

Tags: html, shiny, r-markdown

I would like to ask how to save `rmarkdown`  as html when including `shiny` features.
I know hot to save basic markdown but when including shiny it is not prettz straight forward

For example is it possible to save code bellow as interactive html?

```
---
title: "Line graph"
output: html_notebook
runtime: shiny
---
```

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
selectInput("data","Proměnné modelu",names(mtcars))
```

```
renderPlot({
    x <- input$data
    ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x)) +
      geom_histogram(bins = 15, color = "black", fill = "dodgerblue", aes(y=..density..)) + 
      geom_density(inherit.aes = T, fill="#FF6666", alpha = 0.2)
})
```

```
model <- lm(hp ~ mpg + gear + cyl + disp, data = mtcars)
stargazer::stargazer(model, type = "text")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to export shiny inside a markdown without having R open to read it.

I advise you to look at [there](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/interactive-docs.html).

I hope it helps.